# Need clarification on the proper way to Authenticate (Android app)

Tags: android, spring, firebase, authentication

We have implemented a Backend Server and a DataBase, with RESTFUL API. We have an Android App that can ask the server to send certain data back.

We want to implement an authentication system on the Android App.

The team suggests that I use Spring and OAuth, but I personally have no experience with those, and am not exactly convinced about the necessity of this approach.

Other friends suggest using FireBase to authenticate the users.

Could I avoid using OAuth/FireBase and simply store in the Server's Database the user's account name and its corresponding hash-salted password, along with the salt? Every request sent from the client would contain the account's name (which could probably be a unique ID generated by the server on the very first request, and saved as a SharedPreference in the phone) and the password in clear. The transmission of the request being done via HTTPS protocol (thus using TLS/SSL), the password in clear would not be revealed.

What are the possible flaws to the suggested approach in the last paragraph? And if it is a flawed approach, considering we already are using Spring for the Server (Backend), should I go for FireBase or OAuth ?

**Additional context**:

Bare in mind that this is the very first largish-scale project that I have been working on (it counts as a 3-credits University course). We are 3 on the project. I'm studying Computer Science but I do not necessarily have a great grasp on all the systems we are using or plan on using.

We are creating an app which allows users to view on a map alerts published by certain databases (we are currently focusing on meteorological alerts) in real-time. We want to be able to implement a login system so that people can receive notifications despite the application being closed (we are allowing users to "subscribe" to areas on the map, to specify the regions they want to receive notifications for).

Answer (score 0):

OAuth, or better OpenId Connect, is a protocol, while FireBase is just one of its'  commerce implementations. It's always better to follow a standard where  possible than to implement your own. To see the full list of the certified OIdcC implementations look at the [OIdC site](https://openid.net/developers/certified/), and I see at least [MITREid Connect](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server) project related to Spring. I think your custom solution will work for your custom case, but only until you think about any extensibility such as Google auth or accessing some 3-rd party API.

Comment: Okay, so FireBase uses OAuth in itself. Thus, integrating FireBase is probably a good way of having authentication. How could I then use the generated userbase from that mode of authentication to be able to associate a certain database of saved information to the authenticated users ?

Comment: You have to study OpenId Connect basics. In general: user provides his credentials to an identity provider, the provider issues a token. Your app then put that token into each request to API and API, based on the information in the token (such as userid, token validity interval, issuer of the token and more) performs the requested action.

Comment: I believe two tokens are used in that process, am I right? App-token, and user-secret token. Are they both temporary and regenerated every so often? Which one can/should I store on the phone of the user?

Comment: I'm not familiar with FireBase, but in terms of OIdC you can get three tokens: Identity token, Access aka bearer token and refresh token. Apps use bearer token each time they call APIs and Refresh one to generate a new pair of Access and Refresh when the bearer expires.